# Multi-scale in Object detection?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, computer-vision, object-recognition

I want to ask about MultiScale Object Detection. For the multiscale, if we have an original image do I need to zoom-in at different scales in the image at a particular point or zoom-out at different scales in the image at a particular point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiscale object detection generally consists in smoothing the image with larger and larger kernels, to check  which objects persist across different scales. So, zoom-out, mostly. You now can have access to the [scale-space representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space) of the image, as shown below.

[image: alley-tree-scale-space]

One  reason is that, without more knowledge, one does not zoom in beyond the pixel width. As illustrated (with humour) in the following picture.

[image: Superresolution]

Meanwhile, in certain conditions, [subpixel resolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34105/15892) or superresolution is possible.

Comment: For the first image, the size of the image is same its just the filter size is increasing I guess. but is it same if we use MATLAB command imresize and downsample the image from 720x940 to 256x256 and then further 128x128 and 64x64?

Comment: `imresize` and `downsample` provide instanced in the large class of scale-space/multiscale techniques. Using the low-pass effect of larger kernels, you can indeed downsample the low-pass images, and obtain something akin to the Gaussian pyramid. YOu can find a description of the above in the survey paper [A Panorama on Multiscale Geometric Representations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5320)